# Javascript code check: token errors when trying to set cookies

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have this in the head section of my page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function makeCookie(name)
        {
            alert("c is for cookie");
            days=30; // number of days to keep the cookie
            var myDate = new Date();
            myDate.setTime(myDate.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
            expires="myDate.toUTCString();
            document.cookie="pull=" + name;
            alert("c is for cookie");
        }
    </script>
```

And then a bunch of list items that look similar to this:

```
<a href="#tab2" onclick="makeCookie("LastName FirstName")">LastName FirstName</a>
```

I'm not getting alerted and no cookie is getting set.  So I know I'm doing something wrong.  When I check out the JavaScript console in Chrome it gives me token errors as well.  So I'm guessing I have a hanging bracket somewhere, but I can't find it.

Comment: Well, there is a single opening quote in this line: `expires="myDate.toUTCString();`, with no associated closing quote.

Comment: You are seriously better off using [tested and trusted](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html) cookie code too. What you have pasted is a mess of open and not closed quotes and new lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because you're using the same type of quotes for `onclick` as you are for the parameters to `makeCookie`, so it thinks you're closing the first set of parenthesis when you do "Lastname. Try:

```
<a href="#tab2" onclick='makeCookie("LastName FirstName")'>LastName FirstName</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

[JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) shows this unmatched open-quote for starters:

```
expires = "myDate.toUTCString();
          ^
```

Additionally, the quotes in your `onclick` values are wrong, you should use single quotes for the inner JavaScript quotes, to avoid ambiguity with the double-quotes that are already there for the HTML attribute.

```
<a href="#tab2" onclick="makeCookie("LastName FirstName")">LastName FirstName</a>
                                    ^                  ^
```

Comment: I upvoted this because it addresses both syntax errors but please add the correct html as well.

Comment: @Esailija as the text describes, replace the indicated double-quotes with single-quotes

Answer (score 0):

Look at the syntax highlighting: the `onclick` attribute is closed prematurely because you're trying to use `"` in a `"`-delimited attribute. Change this:

```
<a href="#tab2" onclick="makeCookie("LastName FirstName")">LastName FirstName</a>
```

to this:

```
<a href="#tab2" onclick="makeCookie('LastName FirstName')">LastName FirstName</a>
```